# The option "Tag (JUnit 5)" does not show up in IntelliJ 2018.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

I am working with JUnit 5.1.0 in a Maven project. I have IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2 (Community Edition). I would like to use the @Tag annotation to describe my tests and be able to filter by those.

The point is that in edit configurations | Configuration | Test Kind there is no "Tag (JUnit 5)" option like I have seen in many examples. Only the option "Tags" is provided.

When I use the option mentioned, I set the field Tag expression to "slow" (without the quotes) (I have one test already tagged like @Tag("slow")).

The point is that no test is found (the test is marked with @Test).

```
@Test
@Tag("slow")
public void testNotBlank() {
  // Given
  String excectedText = "";
  // When
  String text = Checks.notBlank(excectedText, "error");
  // Then
  assertEquals("", Checks.notBlank(text, "error"));
}
```

The pom dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

First of all, I expected to have the option "Tags (JUnit 5)" and I don't. Then, I expected that selecting "Tags" and giving the expression "slow", the test testNotBlank would be executed.

Comment: I have included the correct junit version still the tag option is not shown in intellij idea community version

Answer (score 1):

You can execute tagged tests using the following Test Configuration:

[image]

This can be created using the following steps:

1. Run/Debug configurations > Add new configuration > Junit
2. Select test kind `Tags` and varied configurations as to how you want to execute. e.g. I am executing the test tagged with "fast" N times.

---

Where the test class includes:

```
public class TaggedTests {

    @Test
    @Tag(value = "slow")
    public void sample() {
        System.out.println("slow-test");
    }


    @Test
    @Tag(value = "fast")
    public void fastSample() {
        System.out.println("fast-test");
    }
}
```

and execution outputs:

```
fast-test 
fast-test... 10 times
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not working is because I was using the @Test annotation from JUnit 4 instead of using the one from JUnit 5. Because of that, filtering wasn't working even if JUnit Vintage was imported in the pom.

Answer (score 0):

1)**Configuration in Intellij Junit Runner**

[image: Configuration in Intellij Junit Runner]

Please choose the Tags in the highlighted select box and add your tag to test the tagged test methods alone

2)**Configuration using maven pom.xml**

[image]

Add the above configuration at the  level and your desire tags inside groups tag separated by a comma as shown in the picture with two tags Add and Multiply.